# Can people be killed with conqueror's haki alone?

Tags: one-piece

We know that conqueror's haki is said to be strongest haki that only a few people are lucky enough possess from birth. But so far it has only be used to telepathically knock people unconscious or make your attacks stronger.

Is it possible to kill someone without touching them using only this haki? If yes will it look any different from scaring someone to death?

Comment: There have been no examples of this and there isn't enough information at this time to make a prediction. I personally don't find it likely due to certain developments at the end of the Wano arc.

Comment: !> ! You mean when Shanks scared Ryokugyu.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan99000 just FYI, spoiler block doesn't work on comments, only on posts

Answer (score 5):

Seems very likely, even if there are no concrete examples of that happening.
You say "**only** be used to telepathically knock people unconscious or make your attacks stronger" but apparently Haki is capable of applying actual pressure on objects too.

[image: Shanks on the Mobydick]

When Shanks boars the Mobydick you see that many members of the crew almost faint even if he is still kinda restraining himself. But more importantly ou can also notice that Conqueror Haki applies **physical pressure** on **inanimate** nearby objects, causing actual damage to a ship that had traveled in the Grand Line for years and therefore is probably build to be more resistant than average.
It is true that somehow a tired Law managed to withstand Fujitora tremendous gravity powers, but I doubt your "average Joe" could do the same and withstand Yonko level of Haki pressure. I expect that a random passerby could and would be crushed if the Haki user intent was to cause damage.

To put that into context, here are some feats of Conqueror Haki clashing (notice: do not confuse Armament Haki infusion and Conqueror Infusion - the second one is the one with the black lighting effect).

[image]

[image]

Remember Kaido henchmen fearing that he would simply destroy the whole fortress (and the whole island) if his fight with Big Mom would go on for too much.
I totally expect that it would be reasonable that such force could crush an untrained background character to death.

Anyway it is worth noticing that most of the  extreme example of Haki "explosions" were caused by **two** users clashing. Yet, Shanks example above seems to indicate that an extremely skilled user could at least cause a serious amount of physical pain on a weak, untrained person.

Comment: Good examples, but I think it is important that all the most destructive cases involved the **clashing** of two extremely powerful wills, often amplified by them infusing it into weapons. If one Conqueror's Haki user is targeting a weaker user directly, the worst we've seen is them fainting (i.e. their willpower being crushed, not them physically). It's possible this becomes another "advanced" application, but neither Kaido nor Big Mom did it and very few remaining antagonists have the potential to be Conqueror's Haki users.

Comment: @TheGamer007 point is that you see Haki breaking the wood on a ship. The crew "only" faints, but those aren't average humans. My argument is that if Shank Haki can cause damage to reinforced wood, it probably can cause physical damage to normal persons too.

Comment: That is interesting. But I think crushing someone's will would be easier than applying pressure to kill them. As the later seems like just the side effect of haki.

Comment: Woop Slap would instantly die from Luffy's Conquerors Haki.